# 5V to 3.3V Converter

Tags: cmos, level-shifting, ttl, logic-level

I have a problem in connecting Raspberry PI to an MCP3202. I am using MCP3202 at 5V and knowing that raspberry pi works on 3.3v.  I have found a solution to convert from 3.3V to 5V using 74HCT244.
And now i am searching how can i convert from 5V logic to 3.3V ? Could someone help me. 
Thank you

Comment: If available for the function you need, 74LCX logic can do this (5V tolerant inputs when powered from 3.3V)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a very easy solution you could use this little [sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009) PCB. But I would go for something more robust, like this amazing little [SN74LC1T34](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv1t34.pdf), which is widely used in industry.

---

**Edit:** I see the link I supplied is for a single buffer. the [SN74](https://eu.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Logic-ICs/Buffers-Line-Drivers/_/N-50nah?keyword=SN74) family comes in a variety of shapes and sizes. You will find something that solve your problem.

Comment: i only have 74HCT244. and it is not a 5v tolerant. I know that 74LVC244 should work properly but i can't find one to buy it. So if i can use a resistor devider knowing that the signal is at 2 MHZ?

Comment: A resistive divider for 2 MHz would need careful engineering.  Similarly, that Sparkfun MOSFET thing only has large pullup resistors to drive high, it's more suited to I2C than fast SPI.